# Get everything after a character, even when there are repeats. Python

Tags: python, parsing, irc

I'm writing an IRC bot, and am parsing the message using a whole bunch of splits.
The format for an IRC 'message' is:

```
:username!765a4aa2@gateway/web/freenode/ip.***.***.***.*** PRIVMSG #Channel :Message body
```

In particular is the one that get's the text of the message:

```
message = data.split(':')[2]
```

This get's everything after the last ':'
But when the user sends a link over IRC, then the message will look like:

```
:username!765a4aa2@gateway/web/freenode/ip.***.***.***.*** PRIVMSG #Channel :http://web address.com/
```

and the code will only get the 'http' section of the message, as the rest is now in the third section of the split.

So how can I parse a message containing a link?

One way is to get the lenght of the first section, and remove it:

```
message = data[len(data.split(':')[1])+1:]
```

But I can't help feeling that there must be a better way. Is there one?

Answer (score 3):

`str.split()` accepts an optional argument `maxsplit`.

```
message = data.split(':', 2)
```

Comment: also there is .rsplit() which is this same, but splits from the right.

Answer (score 1):

Set the amount of `:` you want to split:

```
data.split(':', 2)
```

And you'll have:

```
['',
'username!765a4aa2@gateway/web/freenode/ip.***.***.***.*** PRIVMSG #Channel ',
'http://web address.com/']
```